# Разница в написании Python - кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Изучаю Python пару месяцев, и, естественно, у меня накопилось несколько глупых вопросов. Один из них - скобки в циклах, условных операторах и прочее. Не могли ли вы мне объяснить, есть ли разница в написании со скобками или без?

Пример:

```
 while (a > n):
    print(n)
```

Или же:

```
 while a > n:
    print(n)
```

Есть ли разница между ними, и если есть, то какая? Заранее благодарю за ответ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваши примеры одинаковы и выполняют одно и то же.

Скобки могут пригодиться Вам, когда будут сложные условия, например, математические выражения:

```py
while (a + b) * c > n:
    print(n)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ) Просто различные авторы книг любят эти скобки совать в свои книги, а новичку легко запутаться)

Comment: @PythonLearner4823 че-то ни разу не видел скобок в подобных выражениях нигде)

Comment: Да авторы книг по программированию очень любят их вставлять в свои примеры) А я, как неопытный программист, сижу и думаю, а вдруг скобки на что то влияют)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, лучше использовать скобки, чем нет, даже там где не обязательно, тогда другому человеку не придется разбираться с приоритетом операций, в попытке понять, что вы имели виду и т.п. Но в одиночном выражении конечно не стоит использовать, а в длинном условии можно и расставлять скобки.

Например, выражение `while ((a + b) + (not (c > n))) > 1:` визуально трактуется однозначно понятно, без знания приоритета операций, и ошибиться в трактовке условия при таком написании невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Скобками указывается приоритет выполения действий. Например:

```
1 + 2 + 2 * 2 // ответ 7
```

но как только указать приоритет в скобках

```
1 + (2 + 2) * 2 // ответ 9
```

В пайтон умножение учитывается с высшим приоритетом, т.е. вначале умножение, потом прибавлени

Comment: Вопрос был изначально про оборачивание в скобки условия в if или while. К приоритету операций это не имеет отношения, скорее к стилю кода.